# Combining different Types of HashMap in Java to a generic HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

My problems starts here with a limitation with HashMap in Java that does not allow using multiple values for same key. As in my code written below i need to have multiple values for `k5 & k6`.

***map*** is the main hashmap of QueryParameters that i will be passing on to be used in my RestAPI request. 
Approach tried:
Created different Map of String and String[] type and then merge which i found would not be allowed to be merged.*Code of the same has been marked as commented via //*

My REST request looks like the following and i am finding it difficult how to send it in the following manner:

`https://myURL/api&k1[]=value&k2=2value&k5[]=v3&k5[]=v4&k5[]=v5&k6[]=v7&k6[]=v8&k6[]=v8`

If there is any other way to represent this in Java, please do let me know.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("k1", "value");
map.put("k2", "2value");
//String[] k5 = new String[]{"v3", "v4", "v5"};
map.put("k5[]", "v3");
map.put("k5[]", "v4");
map.put("k5[]", "v5");
//String[] k6= new String[]{"v7", "v8", "v9"};
map.put("k6[]", "v7");
map.put("k6[]", "v8");
map.put("k6[]", "v9");
```

Comment: You could have a `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: Can you explain a little more how to put it exactly, so i can test and let you know.

Comment: Or you could use a list: `List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry>`

Comment: @icantcode `map.put("k5", Arrays.asList("v3", 'v4", "v5"));`

Comment: @GBlodgett, what about other values?  would they be put as normal ```map.put("k1", "value");``` or ```map.put("k1, Arrays.asList("value"));```

Comment: @icantcode `Arrays.asList("value")`, or depending on your version you can use `List.of`

Comment: @SlawomirChodnicki can you help me put all of this via your method into the main map? finding it difficult with you way. more details may help.

Comment: Looks like you aren't aware of how a HashMap works. If you put a new value for the *same* key the old/previous value gets over-written/lost. Also, why not just use `Map<String, String[]>`?

Comment: @GBlodgett is it possible to merge ```Map< String, String> and Map<String, String[]>``` by any mechanism?

Comment: @NicholasK would you mind reading the first line of the question?

Comment: You could have a `Map<String, String[]>` but it adding to it would be `map.put("v3", new String[]{"v","foo","bar"});`

Comment: i am finding it difficult write now to combine this across, can you guys help me out with the complete code? Will be much appreciated. write now i am unable to put the whole suggested solution together. @NicholasK but this would not accept the normal ```map.put(String, String)``` since default is ```map.put(String,String[])``` I have both ```String and String[]``` that needs to be put into this map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pretty simple actually. Here's what you'll need to do:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("v3", new String[] { "v", "foo", "bar" });
```

---

If you want to add more elements to this, you can define the map as `Map<String, List<String>>`

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> initialList = new ArrayList<>();
initialList.add("v");
initialList.add("foo");
initialList.add("bar");
map.put("v3", initialList);

// add some new String      
map.get("v3").add("Some_new_string");

// adding a whole new list
map.get("v3").addAll(Arrays.asList("new_element_1", "new_element_2"));
```

Comment: but what about ```map.put("k1", "value");```? It's not of ```String[]``` type.

Comment: Construct an `Array` with a single element

Comment: ah okay, any better way than this to do this in Java then to put each of the keys since they are around 8 and i don't think creating an array of all 8 of them would be optimal?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the value of the map as a *List*. Working with that will be much easier.

Answer (score 3):

You want this map:

```
Map<String, List<String>> strings = new HashMap<>();
```

For adding and removing strings, use
[`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) and [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
// Add str to list of strings indexed by key
strings.computeIfAbsent(key, ign -> new ArrayList<>()).add(str);

// Remove str from list of strings indexed by key
strings.computeIfPresent(key, (i, c) -> c.remove(str) && c.isEmpty() ? null : c);
```

This dynamically creates and removes the Lists in the map. Example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> strings = new HashMap<>();
put(strings, "key", "a"); // ["key" => ["a"]] <-- list dynamically created
put(strings, "key", "b"); // ["key" => ["a", "b"]]
remove(strings, "key", "b"); // ["key" => ["a"]]
remove(strings, "key", "a"); // [] <-- no leftovers
```